# How to export post 2 posts Wordpress plugin data

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, import, export, bulk-import

I have an old website which uses the post 2 posts plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts). The plug in has been used to set up many relationships between custom post types.

However I am now in the process of creating a new version of this website from scratch. I therefore have exported and imported all posts, custom posts and ACF data. However the export / import did not include the relationship data of each post.

My question is how can I export the post relationship data that was created using "post 2 posts" from the old site to new site?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions regarding 3rd-party products tend to go unanswered here as they require very detailed knowledge about those products in order to answer well. As a result, such questions are off-topic here. Your best bet is to pose your question in Posts 2 Posts' official support channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins use 2 custom tables to store relations datas :
https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Data-organization

Then if the plugin has not foreseen a export functionality, you have to retrieve the tables.

Comment: Thank you for that! Importing these tables worked nicely.